# Preserving state upon redirect, no redux or react-router

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a React app as a personal project. I am using OAuth with implicit grant flow, which has my user redirect to a different page for auth, then redirects back to my app. Everything is working as I expect, but when the user is redirected, all my state is cleared.

For example, my user finds a specific book from a list of books, this takes the user from the index page to that specific book's show page, and the book's ID is saved in component's state. When the user wants to save this book to their personal account, they log in through OAuth and come back. Now the book is no longer saved in the state and the user needs to search and find it again as a logged in user. I want to avoid using redux and react-router if possible, and the only workaround that I've thought of so far is to save the book ID into localStorage, which I'm not sure is a good practice.

Is there any other way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect the user to the login page, you can provide a URL param like `afterLoginRedirectionUrl` that contains the book id, e.g. `/books?activeBookId=3`

In the log in component, after success, redirect to that url if the param `afterLoginRedirectionUrl` is present. This way, when going back to `/books?activeBookId=3`, you can set the initial state of your component to the active book id present in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

About your comment:

> I want to avoid using redux and react-router if possible

Redux or react-router won't solve this problem. They store the data in the same way you do it right now, **In memory**, and as soon as you refresh or close the page all the data will be lost.

About using `localStorage`: if it is working for you, you can continue using it. It is standard and supported in all major browsers. In case you are dealing with very structured data, maybe it will be good to take a look to [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) too.